# The method getString() of a ResultSet object in JDBC returns a string value with excessive trailing space

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm writing code for authorizing user login using JSP/Servlet, JDBC in IntelliJ IDEA, connect to a SQL Server database.

I made two classes: LoginBean.java and LoginDao.java. Here are codes:

- LoginBean.java:

```
package com.mvc.bean;

public class LoginBean {

    private String username, password;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

- LoginDao.java:

```
package com.mvc.dao;

import com.mvc.bean.LoginBean;

import java.sql.*;

public class LoginDao {

public static void main(String[] args){


        String username = "quanvtm";
        String password = "12345678";

        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=True;databaseName=UNIFOOD";
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            PreparedStatement statement = null;

            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM NGUOIDUNG WHERE TenDangNhap = ? AND MatKhau = ?");
            statement.setString(1, username);
            statement.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String dbusername = resultSet.getString("TenDangNhap");
                String dbpassword = resultSet.getString("MatKhau");

                if (username.equals(dbusername) && password.equals(dbpassword)) {
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            }
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged the program and realized that the value of variable *dbusername* was `"quanvtm          "` and the value of variable *dbpassword* was `"12345678      "`, **both values were with excessive trailing space**, as you can see in this picture [DebugProgram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Imi.png). Therefore, the comparison in the `if` statement returned `false` although input values were right.

The types of values in column TenDangNhap (means Username in English) and MatKhau (means Password in English) in the table NGUOIDUNG (means Users in English) are both `CHAR(50)`.

How can I fix this error?

Thank you for paying attention to my post and sorry for my bad English. I wish you all a great day!

(From Vietnam with <3)

Comment: Nope, it isn't missing the last double quote. See the "Variables" section in bottom side of your "DebugProgram" screenshot. It clearly says `"quanvtm                       "`, so it's simply with excessive trailing whitespace.

Comment: Amazinggg, I see that, I will try to fix it, thanks a lot<3

Comment: I think that comes from using CHAR(30) rather than VARCHAR for the text field in the database. (I made up the 30, because it's difficult to count blank spaces.)

Comment: Thanks NomadMaker for your answer, I will give it a try. However, I use `trim()` method for two variables `dbusername` and `dbpassword`, it removes excessive trailing whitespace and my function works right!

Comment: Using `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` is almost always the wrong choice, as by definition `CHAR` fields are padded with spaces up to the declared length. If you can change the schema of your database, I recommend switching to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will change the schema of my database and I will take note of this. Thanks everyone!